# Use Webdriver.IO to select element by class

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I use the browser from Webdriver.io and want to select an element with the class  `js-add-board` (which is a button i would like to click) inside this constellation:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="news-sidebar sidebar">
            ..
        </div>
        <ul class="board-list clearfix">
            <li class="js-add-board">
                <a class="board-list-item label" href="#">Add a new board</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is from the styles:

```
.board-list .js-add-board {
    text-align: center;
}
```

What I tried was:

```
browser.element('[js-add-board]');
```

but it returned `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I can see, you should use selector by class, not by attribute.

So, in this case, please try the following:

`browser.element('.js-add-board');`

Comment: element is not a valid function

Comment: yes, it should be replaced with `browser.$('.js-add-board')` for latest version of wdio.

Answer (score 6):

`[js-add-board]` is an attribute selector. It would match things like `<a js-add-board="something">` or `<div js-add-board="1">`.

To match a class, use the CSS class selector: `.js-add-board`

If you *must* use an attribute selector, you could do `[class~="js-add-board"]`, but I don't recommend that.

Tip: when you're trying to figure out the correct selector to use in your end-to-end tests, as long as it's not one of Protractor's Angular-specific selectors you can just run it through `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` and see if it gets anything.

For more on attribute selectors, see [this CSS Tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/).